# Manejando contenido jQuery XMLHttpRequest con PHP carga todo el HTML dentro del DIV

Tags: php, jquery, xml

Estoy pasando un parámetro a PHP para recuperar un contenido concreto usando radio buttons con *name="id_estructura"*. Para ello utilizo el siguiente script:

```
    <div id="modelo"></div>

    <script async language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='id_estructura']").change(function(){ 
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          elegido=$(this).val();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("modelo").innerHTML =
              this.responseText;
            } 
          };
          xhttp.open("POST", "index.php", true);
          xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
          xhttp.send ("elegido="+elegido);
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Que luego recojo con esta función en PHP y muestro en el div "modelo".

```
    $idEstructuraInstant = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'elegido');
    if(isset($idEstructuraInstant)){ 
    ChromePhp::log($idEstructuraInstant);//debug
    $resulEstilos = Estilos::consultaSinFormato($idEstructuraInstant);
    $bucle_Estilos = $resulEstilos[0];
    $cont_Estilos=0;
    $contadorEstilos = count($bucle_Estilos);
    foreach($bucle_Estilos as $itemEstilos):
    if($contadorEstilos!=''){
        echo '<div>CONTENIDO</div>';
    }
    endforeach;
    }
```

Todo funciona bien, el problema es que además del parámetro me devuelve todo el código HTML de la página parent tal y como se ve en la captura adjunta. Alguien sabe por qué?

[image: aquí se ve el fragmento de código que aparece cargado dentro del DIV]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He dado con el error, estaba realizando el open a la misma página (index.php) por lo que entraba en bucle.

```
 xhttp.open("POST", "index.php", true);
```

Uso smarty y no había visto que la página que cargaba era la misma a la que enviaba.

Lo he solucionado trabajando con otro archivo aparte.